# Non-homog 2nd Order DiffEq help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

y'' - 2' + y = xe^x + 4
Homog Y = Axe^x + Be^x

How come the nonhomog is x^3e^x + constant?

First I did xe^x + e^x+ C then multiplied x to the first 2 terms because of repetition with the homog soln, getting x^2e^x + xe^x + C. But then the 2nd term is still a repetition so multiplying that by x gives 2 terms with x^2? I don't know how that becomes x^3

Comment: $y'$ is missing

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please take some time to read [this page on mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you use it your question will look much better, and people will be more happy to put some effort to write an answer. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 1):

When I read your question again I realize that the confusion is the lack of the $x^2e^x$ term. In fact, you cannot see that before you do your ansatz. **It will just happen in your calculations that the constant in front will be zero**. Below is a way to think on why one should multiply with $x$ (which you actually seem to know). There are many ways of looking at this.

You can write your differential equation as
$$
(D-1)^2y=xe^x+4.\tag{$*$}
$$
Looking at the right-hand side, we observe that $xe^x$ satisfies $(D-1)^2xe^x=0$ and that $4$ satisfies $D4=0$. In particular, the right-hand side satisfies
$$
D(D-1)^2\bigl[xe^x+4\bigr]=0.
$$
Next, assume that $y_p$ is a solution to $(*)$. Then we find that
$$
D(D-1)^2(D-1)^2y_p=D(D-1)^2\bigl[xe^x+4\bigr]=0.
$$
Thus $y_p$ solves the homogeneous differential equation
$$
D(D-1)^4y_p=0.
$$
This means that (looking at the characteristic equation) $y_p$ is in the form (I assume that you have a theorem on solutions of homogeneous differential equations)
$$
y_p=A+(C_0+C_1x+C_2x^2+C_3x^3)e^x
$$
From your original differential equation we know that the part
$$
(C_0+C_1x)e^x
$$
satisfies the homogeneous differential equation. Thus, a successful anzats for $y_p$ is
$$
y_p=A+(C_2x^2+C_3x^3)e^x.
$$
Find $A$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ so that $y_p$ solves $(*)$. In your case you will find that $A=4$, $C_2=0$ and $C_3=1/6$.